# Ubuntu (pre-) Installation advice sought

Tags: dual-boot

I run Windows 7 on an adequately-endowed PC: 3.7 GHz quad-core Athlon with 8 GB of RAM.   Windows and various files live on a “C: drive” that is a 500 GB SSD.  Most files live on a 1 TB hard drive, but now a 4 TB USB hard drive is carrying some of the weight.  There’s a DVD reader/writer.  I just installed another 500 GB SSD.

My plan is to put Ubuntu on the new SSD and dual-boot from the two SSDs.  That seems like the cleanest, safest way to make sure that I don’t injure the W7 system while installing Ubuntu; I’ll just disconnect the Windows-bearing SSD and install Ubuntu on the other, from a stick.

I don’t know how I will control which system boots.  I don’t want to do it by cable swapping.  I’d rather not have to catch the BIOS on the MoBo and tell it which way to go.  I’d like something to pop up and offer me my choice – perhaps with a settable default.

My expectation is that both operating systems will be able to access all four mass storage devices.

I think it might make sense, and maybe be ‘smoother,’ to put both OS on one drive, leaving the new 500 GB SSD strictly for file storage.  I’m open to that, but paranoid.

I have considerable CLI experience, from before GUIs, and also from the time that I ran Ubuntu 14.04.3 both at home and at work.  I’m 75, and no longer brilliant.  I can follow instructions, but I’m not going to attempt to (re-)learn the CLI.

I’m especially concerned that halfway through installing Ubuntu I’m going to be dropped into the CLI and told to partition the new drive, correct the parameters on of the graphics card, reset the cursor flash rate, and or other things I don’t know how to do.  I don’t want downtime.  I don’t know how good the installation instructions fir 22.04.3 are going to be.

I’d also like to get my hands on detailed installation instructions, so I know what I’m up against.  Most of what I’ve been able to find is years old.

I’m interested in any advice available on any aspect of the project.

Thanks,

Paul in East Troy

Comment: You mention installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, but not which Ubuntu 22.04.3 product. Have you looked at the installation tutorials; eg. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server# if it's Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Server you're asking about, or https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop if it's the Desktop. Different installers can be used, which are selected at download time by the ISO you grab (Server & Desktop use different installers for example; likewise for some *flavors* too). The server installed has changed between 2014 & 2022, Desktop installer has not.

Comment: FYI:  This is a *Question & Answer* site; which requires a *clearly defined problem* to be solved (the question), which is then answered by people in how they'd achieve it (*different answers can exist using different approaches*).  Details that require *opinions* are off-topic here, as better suited to forums (this isn't a forum) with https://ubuntuforums.org/ being the address of Ubuntu Forums.  As written, I see your question as being better suited to a Forum, rather than Q&A site; as you have no clearly defined *problem* (question) but are seeking *advice* (aka off-topic opinion)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask maybe beneficial   ... FYI: there are many ways you can achieve it; you shouldn't have issues without removing drive(s), but removing it should allow easier correction(s) if you encounter problems... Many changes you'll need to make however are machine *firmware* specific (ie. with multiple drives; working out which is used for booting & selecting which you want to use is machine *firmware* related!)... etc

Comment: First step: make an Ubuntu installation (22.04 desktop version) stick or DVD and boot from it. Use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Make sure everything works. Then update your question.

Comment: If "East Troy" is the one in Wisconsin, look up the Milwaukee Linux User Group. They can help in-person at their monthly meetings.